# "No module named manage" error when trying to debug a Werkzeug Django app in VSCode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, werkzeug

As the title says. I have a Django 4.1 app, which uses Werkzeug to enable https. I have the following launch.json set up:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "python": "${workspaceFolder}/venv/Scripts/python.exe",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\appname\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver_plus",
                "--cert-file",
                "${workspaceFolder}/certs/cert.pem",
                "--key-file",
                "${workspaceFolder}/certs/key.pem"
            ],
            "justMyCode": false,
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run this through the VSCode debugger it immediately quits in the `get_wsgi_application()` function with "No module named manage". I tried googling around, but no answer proved to be useful. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide the workspace directory structure?

Comment: What are you specifically curious about? I think the paths in the question describe everything relevant. It is a standard Django project structure, same they have in their tutorial.

Comment: Any other information?

Comment: What are you specifically curious about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is only specific to VS Code's debugger and it is happening for wrong path in `PYTHONPATH` variable. Hence, this problem will not happen if you run it from shell.

In your case, you need to add a new attribute named `env` in the `launch.json` configuration, [which will add environment variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference). In there you need to update the `PYTHONPATH`, because manage.py is not in the root folder of the project:

```
"configurations": [
        {"env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}\\appname"
            },
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\appname\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver_plus"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "python": "${workspaceFolder}/venv/Scripts/python.exe",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
            ],
            "justMyCode": false,
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: As I said this is a Werkzeug application, therefore it needs runserver_plus...

Comment: and manage.py is _not_ located in the place you indicated it